# After submitting the form, I want to stay at the same page and display the data

Tags: ruby

When I fill my employee form and performance details and click "to submit" button, I want it to show all the data on the same page and I want the form to become empty so that I can refill the form for the same employee again.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgim4.png)

Comment: i want my data to be submitted at the same page when i click on submit button and at the same time it will be displayed down in the form of grid view.

Comment: sound like you use ruby-on-rails. do you?

Comment: yes, i am working on ruby on rails, sorry for not mention :/

Answer (score 2):

Use `redirect_to :back` in your controller to, what for it, redirect back to the previous page (or more accurately HTTP_REFERER)

To ensure the form data is blank, the model it is rendered on should have blank fields with something like `@performance_report = PerformanceReport.new`.

If you want to show both the old data and the blank form, you will need your controller to create two instance variables, one showing previous data, and one empty.